# How do I create a Windows XP compressed folder in Winzip?

Tags: windows-xp, compression, winzip

When you create a compressed folder in Windows XP it appears to be a standard zip file but it's not.  That said WinZip 9.0 (dated 2004) can read it.   However the Windows XP compressed folder support can't read a standard WinZip 9.0 created zip file.

I need to create a Zip file which Windows XP compressed file support can read.  However I'm having great difficulty locating relevant URLs amongst the many other hits.   I don't see anything relevant at the [Winzip Knowledge Base](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create the zip using Windows XP built-in functionality?

You can find the steps here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306531

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 and, if it had that capability, I've either disabled it or installing Winzip has disabled it.

Comment: I don't think you can disable it. Instructions are: Right-click the file or folder, click **Send To**, and then click **Compressed (zipped) Folder**.

Comment: Ahh, oops.   I didn't read your link thoroughly and didn't realize you could right click on the files and Send To.   I'd only ever noticed Step 2 in the past.  Thanks.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Answer (score 1):

"Compressed Folders" are normal Zip archives. However, Windows XP only supports the DEFLATE compression algorithm, and WinZip 9 appears to be using DEFLATE64 by default.

You could try [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Interesting.  When I run the File >> Properties >> Details on both I only see the following.  "compression method 08): deflated" & "compression sub-type (deflation): normal" on both.

Comment: @TonyToews: Does it list Deflate and Deflate64 separately?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you disable options while zipping listed in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Windows_compressed_folders). If you don't use these, Windows should be able to extract WinZIP's zip files.

Comment: Do you mean the options as per "AES Encryption, split or spanned archives, and Unicode entry encoding"?   I haven't made any changes to the Winzip settings themselves and don't see anything relevant.   AES, split/spanned don't apply.   I don't see any options for Unicode in Winzip 9.0.